# Access The Prototype After Using Bind

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that when using `bind` on an object, you lose the ability to access the prototype.

```js
function Foo(obj) {
    this.fields = obj;
}

function Make(obj) {
    return Foo.bind(Foo, obj); 
}

var Test = Make({
    name: 'Jeff' 
});

console.log(Test.prototype);
```

Here's the same example not using `bind`:

```js
function Foo(obj) {
    this.fields = obj;
}

function Make(obj) {
    return Foo; 
}

var Test = Make({
    name: 'Jeff' 
});

console.log(Test.prototype);
```

Are there any ways around this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? There's no way around it as the question is written, but if we knew WHY you want to use bind and access the prototype you'll probably get several answers.

Comment: if you see [ECMAScript® Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5): _NOTE Function objects created using Function.prototype.bind do not have a prototype property or the [[Code]], [[FormalParameters]], and [[Scope]] internal properties._

Answer (score 0):

So judging by the docs.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Bind ties a function to a specific object so that variables inside that object are always used. so when you're calling console.log in your example you're logging the prototype of the function Test. Not the object Test. So you get undefined.

In order to get the object you want try this:

```
console.log(new Test())
```